# MySQL Array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a nice bit of software for a PHP project, and I am currently trying to do a post code lookup to select an address.

The button that I use has three parts (Client Before, Server, Client After) with the first and last being javascript elements.

I have managed to put together the first two fine but need a way as storing an array as a javascript variable for the last section, when I am dealing with single values I normally put `$result["variable"] = $result` in the Client side, then pick this up in the Client After side by using `result["qmsinitialdays"]; ctrl1.setValue(qmsinitialdays);`

However in this example I need to output the following array to store and use as a variable result in a javascript array foreach

```
($file->Rows->Row as $item)
{
$this->Data[] = array('Id'=>$item->attributes()->Id,'StreetAddress'=>$item->attributes()->treetAddress,'Place'=>$item->attributes()->Place);}
```

Comment: what about `json_encode`?

Comment: ok so would that be $result["PostCodeArray"]=???

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading about JSON. It's a JavaScript "array" that many other languages can encode and decode.

with PHP

```
$myjson = json_encode($myarray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

then

```
<script>
var myjson = <?php echo $myjson; ?>;

</script>
```